# How to insert data in 2 tables at the same time

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Public Sub SaveNames(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    SQLConnection.Close()
    MsgBox("succesfully  added")
    SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    Dim SQLStatement As String
    SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO pres(name) VALUES('" & txtPres.Text & "') "
    SQLStatement &= "INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('" & txtVice.Text & "') "
    SaveNames(SQLStatement)
    cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement

End Sub
```

this is my code, when i run this one,it runs smooth but when  i save the records, i get the       .ExecuteNonQuery() error on the public sub.

this is what it says

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('aaa')' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them in the same like this. Make sure you end the statement with `;`. This `DELIMITER` tells MySQL when the syntax ends.

```
Dim SQLStatement As String
    SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO pres(name) VALUES('" & txtPres.Text & "');"
    SQLStatement = SQLStatment + "INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('" & txtVice.Text & "');"
    SaveNames(SQLStatement)
    cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement
```

For a little extra security you should replace `'` with `''`

```
 Dim SQLStatement As String
    SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO pres(name) VALUES('" & Replace(txtPres.Text,"'","''") & "');"
    SQLStatement = SQLStatment + "INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('" & Replace(txtVice.Text,"'","''") & "');"
    SaveNames(SQLStatement)
    cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement
```

Also, Your event for the button has code that is not needed.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SQLStatement As String
    SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO pres(name) VALUES('" & txtPres.Text & "') "
    SQLStatement = SQLStatment + "INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('" & txtVice.Text & "') "
    SaveNames(SQLStatement)

End Sub
```

All the database stuff happens in `SaveNames`.

Answer (score 0):

You could be open to SQL Injection by using txtbox values. You would be better off using parametrised sql.

But Try....

```
Dim SQLStatement As String
SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO pres(name) VALUES('" & txtPres.Text & "'); "
SQLStatement += "INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('" & txtVice.Text & "'); "
SaveNames(SQLStatement)
```

But better still try....

```
Dim SQLStatement As New StringBuilder
SQLStatement.Append("INSERT INTO pres(name) VALUES('").Append(txtPres.Text).Append("'); ")
SQLStatement.Append("INSERT INTO vpres(vname) VALUES('").Append(txtVice.Text).Append("'); ")
SaveNames(SQLStatement.ToString)
```

Comment: one on top is not working, and the second one,it says StringBuilder is not defined

Comment: If you want to use Stringbuilder you must import System.Text

Comment: Ok... set a breakpoint on SaveName(SQLStatement.ToString) then run code. On reaching breakpoint check what SQLStatement.ToString is. You can copy its value and try it directly in MySql to see if it works. One other question are both values STRINGS? i.e. MySQL is not expecting a numeric for either value is it.